# Is it unnecessary to hard code the default configurations while they have already been stored in somewhere else?

Tags: c#, wcf, config

I'm currently participating in a SOA project with tens of WCF services. The business logic configurations of the services are stored in the database and a specific service is responsible for retrieving the configurations. And the default configurations of each service are also hard coded in the corresponding service in case the config service is down or some other exceptions happened.

My question: Are the hard coded configurations unnecessary and ugly? Should we fully trust the configuration service instead of putting a backup of the default settings in the code? More generally, do you hard code the default configurations while they have already been stored in database, etc.?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, hard coding configuration is not suitable and its not easy to maintain as well. If you can't trust your configuration service, then you may store the configurations in a backup XML document and read from there instead of having them as hard coded elements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration often changes after the application is delivered so hard coding them is a recipe for requiring frequent rebuilds. Similarly, storing them in the database is not advisable because it requires the operators to access or modify the database, which breaks "least privilege", and separates them from the database access credentials, making backup and review more difficult.

You generally trust your operators. These people monitor the system and are responsible for its continued operation. You also want "segregation of duties" between the developers and operators and hard coding them breaks this.

Comment: @Mengfei See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_duties for more information. Basically, you split a task into something that two or more people do so one person cannot accidentally or maliciously do something bad.